# Checking if certain cells are recognised

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2016

I have a column in my sheet called `mobile numbers` which contains a list of different mobile numbers. I have another column called `Mobile Match` which has no values in the rows. I'm trying to work out whether the mobile numbers from the list under `mobile numbers` are recognised from a list saved elsewhere. So, there are 2 numbers in the `mobile numbers` column that are recognised. So, for the numbers listed in the `mobile numbers` column", I'm trying to put a `"yes"` if they are recognised from the other list or a `"no"` if they are not in the list in the `"Mobile Match"` column.

Example of what it should look like:

```
Mobile Numbers (A)                    Mobile Match (B)
083274                                        yes
083274                                        yes 
083271                                        no
083274                                        yes 
083273                                        no
```

I've copied in the formulas below which is printing out "yes" for all of the rows but there are rows that should be "no" for numbers that are not acceptable/on the other list.

I've got the following formulas that I'm inserting into the `Mobile match` column:

```
=IFERROR(IF(MATCH(A2,A:A,0), "Yes",), "No")
```

```
=IF(A:A = "083274", IF(A:A = "325783", "yes", "no"))
```

Why is it not working and how to solve it?

Comment: Your question is not clear. I understand you are looking for mobile numbers in Column A but where are the numbers you want to search for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to search the column A for a phone number (or any piece of text), you can use:

```
=IF(ISERROR(MATCH("083274",A:A,0)),"No","Yes")
```

This will look for "083274 in the column A, if it does not find it then it creates an error (#NA), and the IF returns "No", otherwise it returns a "Yes".

If you want to check whether BOTH of the numbers are there, you can use:

```
=IF(OR(ISERROR(MATCH("083274",A:A,0)),ISERROR(MATCH("325783",A:A,0))),"No","Yes")
```

Comment: =IF(AND(COUNTIF(A:A,"083274"),COUNTIF(A:A,"325783")),"yes","no")

Comment: I think you need to show an example of what you want.